# Webgrid Column HTML.ActionLinks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Here is my Webgrid:

```
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 15, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "PListGrid");
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header-a",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        columns: 
            grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("ITEMNMBR", "Part #", canSort: true, 
                   format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.ITEMNMBR),
                   "PCreate", "PartsLabor", new { ITEMNMBR = @item.ITEMNMBR }, null)),
                grid.Column("ITEMDESC", "Part Description", canSort: true)
                        ))
 }
```

When the view loads, and you hover over a link for the ITEMNMBR/Part # column, you see something similar to:

domain.com/PartsLabor/PCreate?ITEMNMBR=ABCDEFG

I also have a viewbag item (CALLNBR).  **How do I get the actionlink to resolve to:**

domain.com/PartsLabor/PCreate?ITEMNMBR=ABCDEFG&CALLNBR=123456

In other words, how do you pass multiple parameters to the Html.ActionLink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new {param = value, param2 = value2}, null)
```

Just plug your model properties in the appropriate place, and note that the param name must match exactly the param name in the Action method signature.
Oh, and don't miss the null at the end, you need it!

Comment: Yeah, leaving the "Null" out causes some fun issues... learned that a while back.  Just wasn't sure how to do the two params.  Thanks!  I'll test it and mark the answer soon as I have a chance... working O/T on my servers and switches atm... YAY :(

Comment: Yep that did it.  Now to figure out how to make the form pull in those values... Thanks again!